# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I am learning android development I came across this error while following a tutorial online, I was asked to run a zip file. On opening the project I'm getting this error

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

    minSdkVersion = 9
    targetSdkVersion = 23
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title says this "Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0" but you can see in your code that the dependencies is looking for:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3
```

The numbers after the : represent the version number. I don't know why your project would look for an older version number, but try to change that to 2.2.0, sync, and see if it works.